# How include/exclude FormControls from validation in large Angular forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In reactive form you can use `AbstractFormControl.disable()` when you want to exclude particular FormControl/FormGroup from validation. And you can use `AbstractFormControl.enable()` to do the oposite. But sometimes it is not as easy with large complex forms.

Consider following form:

[image]

- green area is present only if B is checked
- blue area is present only if E is checked
- red area is present only if X is checked

The code for the above picture:

```js
   @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `<div [formGroup]="form">
          <div style="float: right">
            <label for="ctrlX">X</label>
            <input type="checkbox" formControlName="ctrlX" />
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <label for="ctrlA">A</label>
            <input type="text" name="ctrlA" formControlName="ctrlA" />
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <label for="ctrlB">B</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ctrlB" formControlName="ctrlB" />
          </div>

          <div *ngIf="form.value.ctrlB === true">
            <div [formGroup]="form.get('detailB')">
              <div class="row">
                <label for="ctrlC">C</label>
                <input type="text" name="ctrlC" formControlName="ctrlC" />
              </div>

              <div class="row" *ngIf="form.value.ctrlX === true">
                <label for="ctrlD">D</label>
                <input type="text" name="ctrlD" formControlName="ctrlD" />
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <label for="ctrlE">E</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="ctrlE" formControlName="ctrlE" />
              </div>

              <div *ngIf="form.value.detailB.ctrlE === true">
                <div [formGroup]="form.get('detailB').get('detailE')">
                  <div class="row">
                    <label for="ctrlF">F</label>
                    <input type="text" name="ctrlF" formControlName="ctrlF" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <label></label>
            <button>Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>`,
      styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
    })
    export class AppComponent  {
      private form = this.formBuilder.group({
        ctrlA: ['', Validators.required],
        ctrlB: [false],
        detailB: this.formBuilder.group({
          ctrlC: ['', Validators.required],
          ctrlD: ['', Validators.required],
          ctrlE: [false],
          detailE: this.formBuilder.group({
            ctrlF: ['', Validators.required]
          })
        }),
        ctrlX: [true],
      });

      constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
    }
```

Now the thing is, that you don't want to validate something, that is not visible to the user. But the question is: **How to implement this correctly?**

Here is what i tried so far.

**A**: toggling controls one by one demonstrated in this [live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a45hsa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)
This works as expected, but there are two downsides:

- code is lengthy, unclear and therefore quite error prone in my opinion
- this way, some controls are dependent on more than one condition, so you need to combine the conditions as well as merge the `valueChanges` observables (for example F is dependent not only on E but on B as well)

**B**: toggling parent formGroups instead of particular formControls demonstrated in [live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drwpvk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)
Problem is that `FormGroup.disable()` recursively changes status of each descendant which leaves and form in an inconsistent state compared to UI.

In those live examples you can see what in enabled in the textarea on the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this.formGroup.setValidators(ValidatorFunction)`. The Validator function can accept formGroup as a parameter. You can check values and return the error object or null. You dont need to depend on any observable here (removes your cons in condition A, the code may be lengthy depending upon conditions). As for B, the form will always be in a consistent state since you are not manually enabling/disabling the controls.

Comment: I'm running into similar problems as OP, and your suggestion doesn't actually seem to work. If you could take a look at this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-m424mb

It's a simple form group with two required controls, and a custom validator that always returns null. According to your statement, this setup *should* cause the group to always be valid, even if both controls are empty, but this is not the case.

It seems that the custom validator is only additional, but doesn't replace the internal validation that relies on the validity of the child controls.